# python string template : Error 'must be convertible to a buffer, not Template'

Tags: python, string, templates, httplib

I use httplib and a string template.

With a normal String as message, it is working, with a template I get :

> Error 'must be convertible to a buffer, not Template'

```
    message=str(SMessage.substitute(...
    webservice = httplib.HTTP(host)
    webservice.putrequest("POST", url)
    ....
    webservice.send(message)
```

Do I need to convert my template, somehow ?

Comment: Consider using `httplib.HTTPConnection` instead of `httplib.HTTP`.

Answer (score 0):

`Template.substitute()` method returns a string, you can drop `str()` around the call. It also means that there might be another assignment to `message` that is not shown in your code snippet that changes `message` from `str` to `Template` or the error is raised in the different place (a full traceback can show where).